# Using input type time on mobile devices

Tags: html

I am using an `<input type="time" step="1500">` in a mobile application (website put in a webview). The problem is that the step does not work in either Android or iOS.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there any other option except using a special library to create that time input?

Answer (score 0):

step 1500 is correct? i dont think so. 
Step specifies the legal number intervals in the time field.

For seconds:

```
Use numbers that will eventually reach "60". Like: "1, "2", "10", "30", etc.
```

For milliseconds:

```
Start with "." and use numbers that eventually will reach "1000". Like ".010", ".050", ".20", etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bw-input">
  <label>Hours</label>
  <input type="time" v-model="hours" step="900" min="00:00" max="12:00">
</div>
```

Step should work, in the code above you will see users have the option to submit time with a step of 15 minutes / 900 seconds. When a user enters anything between 08:00 and 08:15 a message will show:
[image: Warning message if wrong time is entered]

The warning will show on submit.